# how to pass a generic file stream as a parameter?

Tags: c++, stream, fstream

I have this function:

```
void check_open (ifstream& file)
{
    if (not file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

but I can only pass ifstream arguments, how can i make it to accept also ofstream arguments?

Comment: This function really doesnt seem to do much, since it requires is_open to exit. You could drop the function and use an assert in the calling code assert(file.is_open()).
But if your keen, you could make this a template funciton, tehn it would work for any type that defined is_open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the stream has an `is_open()` method, the function below works just fine (`fstream`, `ifstream`, `ofstream`, and the variants of them with different character types).

```
template<typename stream_type>
void check_open (const stream_type& file)
{
    if (not file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I never used templates, now I know how useful are them

Answer (score 1):

Accepting a (reference to a) common base class of those classes should do the trick.

```
void check_open (std::ios &file)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But `is_open` is neither present in `std::ios` nor in `std::basic_ios<char>`

Comment: @P0W But since it **is** defined in one of the subclasses, one can use polymorphism (a `dynamic_cast` etc.) and convert the base class type to the appropriate derived class type, on which one can then call the required method.

Answer (score 0):

try an exciting dabble into template territory:

```
template<typename F>
void check_open (F& file)
{
    if (not file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, redundant, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Pass only the filename in the function and use `ifstream` or `ofstream` inside the function.

Comment: But how will the function know if the caller want an input or an output stream?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Your question should be to OP, I'm just helping to achieve what he wants :)

Comment: What the OP wants is to check if a *stream* is open and exit the program if not. Passing a file name in no way helps with that.

Comment: @john I mean to say that even if you overcome the issue of passing generic pointer(i.e. OP's issue is resolved), Joachim's question would still remain, so this question should be properly redirected.

Comment: @theharshest no with templatized routine, you don't have to know the stream type